# Apache hangs frequently, needs restart to work again

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

i am having issues tuning apache. My current mpm event configs are

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
  ServerLimit               24
  StartServers               8
  MinSpareThreads          512
  MaxSpareThreads          768
  ThreadsPerChild           64
  MaxRequestWorkers       1536
  MaxConnectionsPerChild  5000
</IfModule>
```

if i continuously press ctrl+r on my site for like 20 sec apache hangs, and i need to restart the server On heavy traffic hours also it happens, usually in a day more than 5 times i am facing a downtime. I am reading forums for tuning apache mpm event but not able to figure out.Can anyone please help on this issue or suggest a change or so in my current setup to achieve max performance without hanging apache. I am using an Amazon m3 large instance with ubuntu

**server status shows such output**

```
Current Time: Monday, 22-Jun-2015 06:42:39 UTC
Restart Time: Monday, 22-Jun-2015 06:20:47 UTC
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 21 minutes 52 seconds
Server load: 0.05 0.12 0.14
Total accesses: 5551 - Total Traffic: 51.7 MB
CPU Usage: u41.07 s7.28 cu0 cs0 - 3.69% CPU load
4.23 requests/sec - 40.3 kB/second - 9.5 kB/request
98 requests currently being processed, 862 idle workers
PID Connections Threads Async connections
total   accepting   busy    idle    writing keep-alive  closing
28956   2   yes 2   62  0   0   0
28957   5   yes 4   60  0   0   1
28958   2   yes 2   62  0   0   0
28959   0   yes 0   64  0   0   0
28961   3   yes 2   62  0   0   0
28962   11  yes 11  53  0   0   0
28963   7   yes 7   57  0   0   0
29229   8   yes 8   56  0   0   0
29266   7   yes 7   57  0   0   0
29268   5   yes 5   59  0   0   0
29501   9   yes 10  54  0   0   0
29606   12  yes 10  54  1   0   1
29760   18  yes 18  46  0   0   0
30386   11  yes 11  53  0   0   0
30453   1   yes 1   63  0   0   0
Sum 101     98  862 1   0   2
___WW___________________________________________________________
__________WWW_W_________________________________________________
_______________WW_______________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________W_W_
_____W___W__W_______________WWWWWWWW____________________________
_____________________WWWW____________________________________WWW
____________________________________________WWW_WWWWW___________
____________________________________________WW________WWW_____WW
________WWWW__________________W_________________________________
__________W________WWWWWWW_____W____________________________W___
__________________________________WW__WW____WW_WW__W__________W_
_____W________W______WW_W__WWWWW__W__WWWWW_W_________________W__
WWWWWWWWWWW_____________________________________________________
______W_________________________________________________________
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
```

Comment: @AD7six can u explain in detail ?  coz during the down time if i check for free memory it still shows more than 6 GB free out of 7.5

Comment: Can depend on your site code too, its too large as a question without more detail, as I guess same load with a plain html file would crash nothing.

Comment: yes @yagmoth555 ..plain html files are working smooth.. So what can be done in this case? like should i do some more debugging ? if yes can u please guide me, which parameters should i consider

Comment: I had sites running for years with no issues in Apache 2.2 but after upgrade to 2.4 on the same machine and OS it now hangs every few weeks. Nothing in the logs at all.